# Better way to display multiple plugin output on the same page?

Tags: shortcode, html

Using two plugins on one page; promoslider & events list.
Tried to produce desired output.

```
+-----------------+
|  slider output  |
+-----------------+
Text related to events list
+-----------------+
|  events output  |
+-----------------+
```

Code listed below did not produce expected results.

```
// original code
[promoslider width="600px"]
Text related to events list
[events_list]
```

Instead produced output out of order.

```
Text related to events list
+-----------------+
|  slider output  |
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
|  events output  |
+-----------------+
```

Encapsulated short codes in html table seems resolve the issue

```
// Table code
<table>
<tr><td>[promoslider width="600px"]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text related to events list</td></tr>
<tr><td>[events_list]</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there a better way to display multiple plugins on the same page?

Comment: @mrwes: Can you add links to the specific plugins you use? There are multiple plugins that use the shortcode `events_list` for example. It is possible that this is a problem with how the plugin works.

Comment: @mrwes: The `[promoslider]` shortcode, is it added by [the Promotion Slider plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/promotion-slider/)? (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: @Jan - The plugins are Promotion Slider [link] (http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/plugins/promotion-slider/) shortcode is [promoslider] and Events Manager Extended [link](http://www.e-dynamics.be/wordpress/) the shortcode is [events_list]

Comment: @mrwes: Do you have an link where we can see this incorrect behavior? From a quick look at the Promotion Slider code it looks like it should be displayed where you put it in the text, and not move around.

Comment: @jan I created a temp link [link](http://lathropchamber.org/temp) I'm actually using the width parameter [promoslider  width="600px"].  When width parameter used, the text disappears behind promo slider.  When width parameter not used, the text appears to the right of promo slider.

Comment: @mrwes: That promoslider has the class `.random`, and in your `style-Red.css` file you give it a `float: left; width: 200px`. But because your promo slider is actually 600 pixels wide, you have 400 pixels that overlap with what follows: your text. So I don't think this is a WordPress issue but a CSS issue.

Comment: @jan - Thanks for the feedback. I was pretty sure it wasn't WordPress.  So, the width parameter value in promo slider is contradicting the theme CSS.  This makes a lot of sense.  I definitely have a lot to learn about WordPress theme style interaction with plugins.  Any suggested websites or books to help in my education?

Comment: @mrwes: I moved my comment to an answer so you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and this question moves from the "unanswered" list. I don't have a specific recommendation for where to learn CSS, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promo slider on your demo site has the class `.random`, and in your `style-Red.css` file you give it a `float: left; width: 200px`. But because your promo slider is actually 600 pixels wide, you have 400 pixels that overlap with what follows: your text. So I don't think this is a WordPress issue but a CSS issue.